# UI-Router control view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building a single page app with Angular and UI-router. I have the following structure:
[image]

I'm trying to archieve the following: 
I have all news preloaded already in an array.
When I got to `/articles` URL I should see this page with selected the first news by default.
When I click on any of the news the URL should become `/articles/news-2` for example and the the data should change. Note that I already have the information in an array and I already have the template (in the #current-article div), so I don't want to use nested views.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="current-article">
    <img class="current-article-img" ng-src="/static/img/products/{{current.image}}">

    <div class="text-wrapper">
        <div class="current-article-heading">
            {{current.title}}
        </div>
        <div class="current-article-text">
            {{current.fulltext}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="articles-holder">
    <div class="head">
        Още статии
    </div>
    <div class="articles">
        <div ng-repeat="article in articles" class="article">
            <div style="float: left; width: 39%;">
                <img ng-src="/static/img/products/{{article.thumb}}">
            </div>
            <div class="article-content">
                <div class="heading">
                    <a ng-href="/article/{{article.url}}">{{article.title}}</a>
                </div>
                {{article.fulltext | dots}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript looks like:

```
$stateProvider
            .state("article", {
                url: "/article",
                templateUrl: '/partials/interesting.html',
                controller: 'articleCtrl'
            })
```

How I can archieve the described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite of your wish:

> ...Note that I already have the information in an array and I already have the template (in the #current-article div), so I don't want to use nested views...

Nested-views are **the** solution *(here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6xY8Pa?p=preview))*. And I guess that reason *(why you want to avoid nested-views)* would be: to avoid reloading *(articles are already loaded)*. But with nested views/states we can achieve that.

And I would even say, that 1) your requirement and 2) nested views == That's why we have `ui-router`..

So, these are our states:

```
$stateProvider
    // parent 
    .state('articles', {
      url: "/article",
      templateUrl: 'articles.tpl.html',
      controller: 'ArticleCtrl',
    })
    // detail
    .state('articles.detail', {
      url: "/{title}",
      templateUrl: 'article.detail.tpl.html',
      controller: 'DetailCtrl',
    });
```

And here is the parent controller, which will load the data - but only once:

```
.controller('ArticleCtrl', ['$scope',  '$state',
  function($scope, $state) {

    // the loaded array
    $scope.articles = [
      {title: "title 1",fulltext: "fulltext 1"}, 
      {title: "title 2",fulltext: "fulltext 2"}, 
      {title: "title 3",fulltext: "fulltext 3"}
    ]; 

    $state.go("articles.detail", {title:"title-1"});
  }
])
```

The detail would just find the `article` by *title* and display it in main area. It will search for them in the already loaded **`$scope.articles`**. Because that's what `ui-router` and nested views gave us - child can access stuff processed in parent:

```
.controller('DetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
  function($scope, $stateParams) {

    var code = $stateParams.title.replace(new RegExp('-', 'g'), ' ')
    var index = _.findIndex($scope.articles, { title: code });

    $scope.current = $scope.articles[index];
  }
])
```

The working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6xY8Pa?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It helped me a lot to figure out how to do such stuffs in angular.

Comment: Great to see that, `ui-router` is unbelievable piece of code